# Error SMTP: Failed to connect socket: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, smtp

I am getting an error with SMTP: "Error SMTP: Failed to connect socket: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

This is my code

```
$from = "examplewebsite.com";
```

**to mail**

```
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
```

**host name**

```
$host = "website.com ";
$username = "info@website.com";
$port = "465";
$password = "password";
```

**headers**

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
```

**information in array**

```
$smtp = Mail::factory(
    'smtp',
    array (
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    )
);
```

**mail function**

```
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

**pear check, and error message**

```
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo($mail->getMessage());  
} 
else {   
    echo("Message successfully sent!");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a DNS failure, probably caused by the stray space in `$host = "website.com ";`, causing it to look up a non-existent domain.

Comment: It is  showing  error agian Failed to connect to website.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection timed out (code: -1, response: )]

Comment: Connecting to port 465 implies you're using SSL, but there's no sign of that in your config. I doubt you need to specify `smtp` within `$host` - it would be a strange place to put it. You could always (just a wild guess here) try [reading the docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php)...

Comment: Could you tell me please how to write it smtp with my existing code

Answer (score 0):

**I just add these lines in my code and issue resolved**

```
$host = "ssl://websitename.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$port = "465";
```